# Developing a MP3 Player using C#

Tags: c#, winmm

I'm currently developing a MP3 player using C#. I'm a beginner. I have been able to develop a normal  MP3 player with minimal functionalities like open file, pause, play and stop. But the problem is it plays some songs and doesn't play some. I have imported the winmm.dll file too. But some files are played while some are not.Moreover can anyone suggest how can I add a stack of songs to it which will play randomly?The code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace MP3Player
{
    class MusicPlayer
    {
        Boolean isPlay=false;
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern long mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, StringBuilder  lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);
        public void open(String file)
        {
            string command = "open \"" + file + "\" type MPEGVideo alias MyMp3";
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
            isPlay = false;
        }

        public void play()
        {
            if (isPlay == false)
            {
                string command = "play MyMP3";
                mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
                isPlay = true;
            }

        }
        public void pause()
        {
            if (isPlay == true)
            {
                string command = "pause MyMP3";
                mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
                isPlay = false;
            }
        }
        public void stop()
        {
            string command = "stop MyMp3";
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
            isPlay = false;

            command = "close MyMp3";
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why your app doesnt play some mp3s, i think i can assume its because of the audio encoding, but dont quote me.

As for your "Shuffle feature"

what you can try to implement is an array that looks in a directory and and gets all the mp3 files in that directory,

then it randomly plays a song,

heres a sample code:

```
fileinfo MySongs() = MySongDirectoryString.getFiles();
foreach (song in MySong)
{
string SongName = song.tostring();
//code to play that song
}
```

Comment: to make it random, just add a random function to pull a random item out the array similar to this

SongName.Value=MySongs[new Random().Next(0,MySongs.Length) ] ;

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Windows Media Player SDK. Here's an [example](https://github.com/vorou/play.NET/blob/master/Src/playNET/Player.cs).

Answer (score 0):

For your random playing.
Use a stack (makes it easier to track progress)

```
//Retrieve a list of files from a directory.
var di = new DirectoryInfo("Path to folder");
//Get the files and order them randomly.
var listOfFiles = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(s=> Guid.NewGuid);
//Convert the list to a stack.
var stack = new Stack<FileInfo>(listOfFiles);
```

Now you can use your stack with the Pop method to get the next random song in the list.

```
//Usage
var current = stack.Pop();
```

As for the not playing issue, you might want to use LAME encoder/decoder for your mp3 files it's more robust than the windows dll.

Comment: Instead of LAME Naudio is a managed c# library => http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.be/2009/10/naudio-13-release-notes.html
and http://naudio.codeplex.com/